# HAProxy configuration in OpenShift

Tags: node.js, openshift, haproxy

I am new to HAProxy as well as OpenShift. Following is the setup I am trying to do - serve blog through Ghost(a NodeJS app), static website files through PHP cartridge(I assume this is the best way for serving static HTML/JS on OpenShift) and actual application. I would like to route requests to specific gear based on the URL.

[image: HAProxy on OpenShift]

I want to confirm if this is the correct way to set it up. Could you please give some pointers about the HAProxy configuration for this?

Comment: I thought you can't change HAProxy config directly except ssh into it. And once you spin up all three gear, you no longer have any free gear for scaling(if you are paying then of course you can). Why choose PHP to server static files?

Comment: @wayne Yes, agree I would pay for the extra gear to scale. Do you recommend using NodeJS instance itself for serving the static files?

Comment: I would recommend 1) nginx(just type "nginx" in gear search). 2) simple node without framework like express. use only visionmedia/send. 3) PHP

Answer (score 0):

I think that rather than do that in the haproxy it would be worth either running a separate gear for your static assets, or using Amazon S3 or CloudFront for static assets.